# Calling $setViewValue in a directive doesn't fire $watch in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, digest, angular-ngmodel

I am using a directive with a ngModelController like this

```
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel'
  }
```

My link function does something like this (I omitted the long directive stuff)

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

  scope.updateModel = function(){
    var newModel = {};
    newModel.aValue = 'foo';
    ctrl.$setViewValue(newModel);
  }

}
```

I use the directive in my controller

**View: this is correctly updated**

```
<my-directive ng-model="aModel">
  {{aModel.aValue}} // This is changed correctly when I update the value in the directive
</my-directive>
```

**Controller: here is where I have problems**

```
$scope.aModel = {};
$scope.aModel.aValue = 'bar';

$scope.$watch('aModel', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('aModel changed'); // This is never fired
});

$scope.$watch('aModel.aValue', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('aModel changed'); // This is neither fired
});
```

The documentation of `$setViewValue` says

> "Note that calling this function does not trigger a $digest."

so I tried to fire it manually with `$render`, `$digest` or `$apply`, but every time run into trouble since the console says that the `$digest is already in progress`.
So what's the problem with this?

**UPDATE**

I just realized something really interesting.
Adding a `$timeout` to check the value in the controller, I realized that it is not actually changed and that's probably why the $watch function is not called.
But since the view is updated, I don't really get the point.

This is the situation:

**Controller**

```
$timeout(function(){
  console.log('Check aModel value in the controller');
  console.log($scope.aModel.aValue); // This is always 'bar' even if the view display 'foo'
},10000);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think I found the problem: ngModel cannot be an object but it must be a value.
I leave the question open to see if anyone comes with a different solution, but I guess that's the point.

**UPDATE 3**
I was wrong, you can update the ngModel as object, but there is no way to fire the $watch method.
I create [a plunker to show the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2rIZryjucgSPxYzRZB3?p=preview).
I put a large timeout to avoid any $digest in progress problem.
Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add third parameter `true` to `$watch` function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout with no time parameter in order to call $apply and trigger the digest loop. This will cause it to execute a fraction of a second later and not run into the digest loop in a digest loop error. Clearly what your doing is not 'angular aware' and so you need to trigger the digest loop using $apply but your in a digest loop so you need to use the 'hack' mentioned above.